# UNION ALL returning results similar to UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am learning SQL from the Querying Data with Transact-SQL with Edx. However, I think there is some problem with the part using UNION ALL syntax.

First the tutorial created a table called Employees with 337 rows of first names and last names. Then I want to UNION ALL the first name, last name of the Employee tables to the first name, last name of the Customer table (which has 847 rows - with a lot of duplicate names). The following code is what I typed.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM SalesLT.Employees
UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM SalesLT.Customers
ORDER BY LastName;
```

However, the code only returned 441 rows. This by itself is problematic as when you union ALL two sets of tables with 337 rows and 847 rows, it should return 1184 rows! The Union all syntax for this particular question is as good as Union (removing duplicates). Where's my error?

PS: (in the tutorial, UNION ALL is supposed to union all the rows without removing duplicates)

EDIT: After running the count code as follows: It indeed does add up:

```
SELECT COUNT(FirstName) FROM SalesLT.Employees; --337 rows
SELECT COUNT(FirstName) FROM SalesLT.Customers; --104 rows
```

Is it because the tutorial created the employee table as such.

```
CREATE VIEW [SalesLT].[Customers]
as
select distinct firstname,lastname
from saleslt.customer
where lastname >='m'
or customerid=3;
GO
CREATE VIEW [SalesLT].[Employees]
as
select distinct firstname,lastname
from saleslt.customer
where lastname <='m'
or customerid=3;
GO
```

Comment: You're missing the beginning of the query.  I.e. there's no initial SELECT clause.  Are you doing a SELECT or a SELECT distinct?  Also what are the results of the following queries?  SELECT COUNT(FirstName) FROM SalesLT.Employees; SELECT COUNT(FirstName) FROM SalesLT.Customers;

Comment: Can you please advise the results of the following two queries?
    SELECT COUNT(FirstName) FROM SalesLT.Employees;
    SELECT COUNT(FirstName) FROM SalesLT.Customers;

Comment: If your query#1: "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM SalesLT.Employees" returns 337 rows and query#2: "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM SalesLT.Employees ORDER BY LastName" returns 847 rows, then the query you have posted would always return 1184 rows. Please check if you have a DISTINCT/UNION/EXCEPT etc. somewhere in your original query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database is therefore doing exactly what you asked it to do.  Select distinct in the statements which create the Views means that duplicate rows will be removed from the resultset whenever selecting from the views.

By the way it's important to recognise the difference between Views and Tables.  I don't use Views alot myself but when I do, I prefix them with vw so I'm constantly reminded that I'm not looking at the raw table.

That's not to mention that your views have additional selection criteria in them as well (e.g. lastname <='m' or customerid=3;).  Because the VIEWS filter out alot of rows (via the DISTINCT and the WHERE criteria) the numbers were unlikely to match up.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is no problem.

```
select * from a union all select * from b order by c;
```

Comment: Two issues wrong with your answer:  Firstly a and b are table names and c is a fieldname.  Secondly How do you know that table a and table b have all the same fieldnames?